# Is there a way to hide scrollbar in Material UI Table sticky header?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui, scrollbar

I have a Material-UI Table with a fixed header in a React project (reference: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header). I would like to hide the scrollbar in the table header (which overlaps it), while still showing it in the table body.

I have mostly tried changing the `overflow` property in the `TableContainer`, `Table`, `TableHead`, and `TableBody` components, though with poor results. Searching around a bit, it seemed that this problem could be solved setting the `display` property of the aforementioned components to `block`. However, this approach let me only move the scrollbar from the `TableContainer` component to the `Table` component, not solving the issue and messing up the table layout.

**Edit**

Working example:

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

**Wanted Beahviour**
[image]

Comment: Without Your code is very difficult to help you. Please try your code for example on codepen and so post here so someone can help you.

Comment: I added a codesandbox example. However, it does not add anything to the question because it is the same code in the provided link.

Comment: Instead making attempts in the inspector, try to make attemps in the sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { AutoSizer, Column, Table } from 'react-virtualized';

const classes = {
  flexContainer: 'ReactVirtualizedDemo-flexContainer',
  tableRow: 'ReactVirtualizedDemo-tableRow',
  tableRowHover: 'ReactVirtualizedDemo-tableRowHover',
  tableCell: 'ReactVirtualizedDemo-tableCell',
  noClick: 'ReactVirtualizedDemo-noClick',
};

const styles = ({ theme }) => ({
  // temporary right-to-left patch, waiting for
  // https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/454
  '& .ReactVirtualized__Table__headerRow': {
    ...(theme.direction === 'rtl' && {
      paddingLeft: '0 !important',
    }),
    ...(theme.direction !== 'rtl' && {
      paddingRight: undefined,
    }),
  },
  [`& .${classes.flexContainer}`]: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  },
  [`& .${classes.tableRow}`]: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  [`& .${classes.tableRowHover}`]: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
    },
  },
  [`& .${classes.tableCell}`]: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  [`& .${classes.noClick}`]: {
    cursor: 'initial',
  },
});

class MuiVirtualizedTable extends React.PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    headerHeight: 48,
    rowHeight: 48,
  };

  getRowClassName = ({ index }) => {
    const { onRowClick } = this.props;

    return clsx(classes.tableRow, classes.flexContainer, {
      [classes.tableRowHover]: index !== -1 && onRowClick != null,
    });
  };

  cellRenderer = ({ cellData, columnIndex }) => {
    const { columns, rowHeight, onRowClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <TableCell
        component="div"
        className={clsx(classes.tableCell, classes.flexContainer, {
          [classes.noClick]: onRowClick == null,
        })}
        variant="body"
        style={{ height: rowHeight }}
        align={
          (columnIndex != null && columns[columnIndex].numeric) || false
            ? 'right'
            : 'left'
        }
      >
        {cellData}
      </TableCell>
    );
  };

  headerRenderer = ({ label, columnIndex }) => {
    const { headerHeight, columns } = this.props;

    return (
      <TableCell
        component="div"
        className={clsx(classes.tableCell, classes.flexContainer, classes.noClick)}
        variant="head"
        style={{ height: headerHeight }}
        align={columns[columnIndex].numeric || false ? 'right' : 'left'}
      >
        <span>{label}</span>
      </TableCell>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { columns, rowHeight, headerHeight, ...tableProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <Table
            height={height}
            width={width}
            rowHeight={rowHeight}
            gridStyle={{
              direction: 'inherit',
            }}
            headerHeight={headerHeight}
            {...tableProps}
            rowClassName={this.getRowClassName}
          >
            {columns.map(({ dataKey, ...other }, index) => {
              return (
                <Column
                  key={dataKey}
                  headerRenderer={(headerProps) =>
                    this.headerRenderer({
                      ...headerProps,
                      columnIndex: index,
                    })
                  }
                  className={classes.flexContainer}
                  cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
                  dataKey={dataKey}
                  {...other}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Table>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    );
  }
}

MuiVirtualizedTable.propTypes = {
  columns: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      dataKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      numeric: PropTypes.bool,
      width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
  headerHeight: PropTypes.number,
  onRowClick: PropTypes.func,
  rowHeight: PropTypes.number,
};

const VirtualizedTable = styled(MuiVirtualizedTable)(styles);

// ---

const sample = [
  ['Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0],
  ['Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3],
  ['Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0],
  ['Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3],
  ['Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9],
];

function createData(id, dessert, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { id, dessert, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i += 1) {
  const randomSelection = sample[Math.floor(Math.random() * sample.length)];
  rows.push(createData(i, ...randomSelection));
}

export default function ReactVirtualizedTable() {
  return (
    <Paper style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <VirtualizedTable
        rowCount={rows.length}
        rowGetter={({ index }) => rows[index]}
        columns={[
          {
            width: 200,
            label: 'Dessert',
            dataKey: 'dessert',
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Calories\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'calories',
            numeric: true,
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Fat\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'fat',
            numeric: true,
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Carbs\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'carbs',
            numeric: true,
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Protein\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'protein',
            numeric: true,
          },
        ]}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0r5w2z?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer! What you showed in the link is exactly what I look for. Just one question: in order to get the same result, is `react-virtualized` needed?

Comment: yes, react-virtualized is needed for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `makeStyles` from material ui like the example you can add :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
container: {
    scrollbarWidth: "none" /* Firefox */,
    maxHeight: 440,
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
      display: "none"
    } /* Chrome */
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: However, with this approach the scrollbar is not visible in the table body.